# Reload page overwrites label by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

i have `selectize.js` Tag field:

```
window.trainer = $('#modalinput-old-trainer').selectize({
    plugins : [ 'remove_button' ],
    valueField : 'id',
    labelField : 'username',
    searchField : [ 'username' ]
});
```

I load the Options via:

```
window.trainer[0].selectize.clear();
window.trainer[0].selectize.clearOptions();
window.trainer[0].selectize.load(function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/ajax/admin/gettrainers",
        success : function(data) {
            callback(data.aviableTrainers);
        }
    });
```

Then i have a modal, where the `selectize.js` input is located. 
By opening the Modal Items are loaded:

```
$.each(response.trainers, function(index, trainer) {
    window.trainer[0].selectize.addItem(trainer.id);
});
```

This works fine. But if i reload the Page, the Items in the input field are no longer Labeled correctly. Instead the label is replaced by the `id` means the `valueField`.
But if i delete the Items and then reload, they are back normal.

Any Idea what am i doing wrong.